# limit users from uploading long video files

Tags: swfupload

I have a website that host videos, I was wondering if there is a way to prevent users from uploading a video file thats length is longer than 10 minutes before sending it to the server.
Am using SWFupload.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SWFUpload has a `file_size_limit` property that can be set via Javascript:

http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/

Unfortunately, there is no way to check the video duration until it is uploaded.

**EDIT**

Using FFMPEG (PHP), you can determine the video duration:

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Comment: i need to limit by video length not size, is there any way?

Comment: @saadlulu: You can use ffmpeg after the video has been uploaded to determine its duration. See my edit.